# How to calculate $R=S\sqrt{\Lambda}S^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

When I think about it, I've never actually calculated this before, $R=S\sqrt{\Lambda}S^{-1}$.

$S=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$\Lambda =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\ 
0 & 18
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Where did you find the expression $\sqrt{\Lambda S}$? I see no context in which calculating that would be necesary.

Comment: @5xum Updated! It's on diagonalization. Specifically finding the square root of A.

Comment: @Amzoti Oh jeeze, It's only the square root of $\Lambda $? Hows does one compute that anyway?

Comment: Your inverse matrix is off by a scalar multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, is positive (semi-)definite, then $\sqrt{A}$ is defined as $S\sqrt{\Lambda}S^{-1}$ where $\sqrt{\Lambda}$ is calculated by taking square roots of all the diagonal entries, i.e. (in your case),

$$\sqrt{\Lambda}=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{18}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Add up the square roots of the diagonal?

Comment: @KarlMorrison No, construct a new matrix. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is $R=S\sqrt{\Lambda }S^{-1}$.
Then $\sqrt{\Lambda}$ is computed by taking the square roots of the eigenvalues along the diagonal.

Comment: Oh, when I do take the values, what do I do with them, add them up?